# How to use a custom font for <TabBarIOS> in React Native?

Tags: ios, react-native, font-family

I'm using the `<TabBarIOS>` component, I've got custom icons working (using [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons)) however I'm struggling to get a custom `fontFamily` on the `<Icon.TabBarItemIOS>` component. I want to be able to change the font of the text labels below each icon.

I've tried adding the style to both the tab bar and the tab bar item, however it returns the error:

```
2016-06-09 17:45:52.449 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Warning: Failed propType: Invalid props.style key `fontFamily` supplied to `RCTTabBar`.
Bad object: {
  "flex": 1,
  "fontFamily": "Roboto-Regular"
}
Valid keys: [
  "width",
  "height",
  "top",
  "left",
  "right",
  "bottom",
  "margin",
  "marginVertical",
  "marginHorizontal",
  "marginTop",
  "marginBottom",
  "marginLeft",
  "marginRight",
  "padding",
  "paddingVertical",
  "paddingHorizontal",
  "paddingTop",
  "paddingBottom",
  "paddingLeft",
  "paddingRight",
  "borderWidth",
  "borderTopWidth",
  "borderRightWidth",
  "borderBottomWidth",
  "borderLeftWidth",
  "position",
  "flexDirection",
  "flexWrap",
  "justifyContent",
  "alignItems",
  "alignSelf",
  "flex",
  "shadowColor",
  "shadowOffset",
  "shadowOpacity",
  "shadowRadius",
  "transform",
  "transformMatrix",
  "decomposedMatrix",
  "scaleX",
  "scaleY",
  "rotation",
  "translateX",
  "translateY",
  "backfaceVisibility",
  "backgroundColor",
  "borderColor",
  "borderTopColor",
  "borderRightColor",
  "borderBottomColor",
  "borderLeftColor",
  "borderRadius",
  "borderTopLeftRadius",
  "borderTopRightRadius",
  "borderBottomLeftRadius",
  "borderBottomRightRadius",
  "borderStyle",
  "opacity",
  "overflow",
  "elevation"
] Check the render method of `TabBarIOS`.
```

I've looked through the docs but can't find anything on the subject, any ideas?

Comment: In my experience TabBarIOS wasn't very customizable outside of objective-c. I ended up using https://github.com/exponentjs/react-native-tab-navigator.

Comment: Could you share how did you get react-native-vector-icons working in TabBarIOS please?

Comment: @SergeySinkovskiy, sure! It's in their docs here: https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#usage-with-tabbarios

Comment: @BradBumbalough Missed your comment, but that's what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to tinker around with the Objective-C bridge if you'd like to adjust the font. For example, in `RCTTabBarItem.m` you have the below setup code. You can use `setTitleTextAttributes` to specify your font.

```
- (void)setIcon:(UIImage *)icon
{
  _icon = icon;
  if (_icon && _systemIcon != NSNotFound) {
    _systemIcon = NSNotFound;
    UITabBarItem *oldItem = _barItem;
    _barItem = [UITabBarItem new];
    _barItem.title = oldItem.title;
    _barItem.imageInsets = oldItem.imageInsets;
    _barItem.selectedImage = oldItem.selectedImage;
    _barItem.badgeValue = oldItem.badgeValue;
  }

  /* set custom font for tabBarItem */
  [_barItem setTitleTextAttributes:@{
      NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Raleway-Bold" size:10.0f]
    } forState:UIControlStateSelected];
  [_barItem setTitleTextAttributes:@{
      NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Raleway-Bold" size:10.0f]
    } forState:UIControlStateNormal];

  if (_renderAsOriginal) {
    self.barItem.image = [_icon imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
  } else {
    self.barItem.image = _icon;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't  feel like adding and entire package to my project just to change fonts, this works like a charms.. cheers!!!